# output as undefined/NAN

Tags: javascript, nan

Would anyone clerify why my program is outputting undefined or NAN? I know for sure that my random number generator is working. Also, I'm trying to sum up all of the "score" value when the number generator has generated the value 10 times. Thanks for the help

```js
<HTML>
<!Foundation Page for building our Javascript programs>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>The Foundation Page </TITLE>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE = "JavaScript">
function main()
 {
 randomnumber()
 totalscore()
 }
function randomnumber()
{
 var randomnumber;
 randomnumber = Math.random()*3;
 return(Math.floor(randomnumber+0.5));

}
function totalscore() 
{
 var n;
 var score;
 var number;
 number = randomnumber()
 for (n=0;n<11; n=n+1)
 {
  if (number==0)
   {
   score =score+0
   }
  if (number==2)
   {
   score =score+2
   }
  if (number==3)
   {
   score =score+3
   }
  document.write(score)
 }
}

</SCRIPT>
<HEAD>
<BODY>
<BODY BGCOLOUR = "WHITE">
<H2>The Foundation Page </H2>
<HR>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE = "Javascript"> main() </SCRIPT>
<INPUT NAME = "dobutton" TYPE = "button" value = "Start game" on Click = "game()"> 
<INPUT NAME = "dobutton" TYPE = "button" value = "Leaderboard" on Click = "leader()">
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `score` variable is `undefined`. You should initialize it with a number for instance: `var score = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize your `score` variable with 0. Until you don't, it's value is `undefined` and when you do math operations on an undefined object, you wil get a NaN error. I have also formatted your code a bit.

```
<HTML>
<!Foundation Page for building our Javascript programs>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>The Foundation Page </TITLE>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE = "JavaScript">
function main()
    {
    randomnumber()
    totalscore()
    }
function randomnumber()
{
    var randomnumber;
    randomnumber = Math.random()*3;
    return(Math.floor(randomnumber+0.5));

}
function totalscore() 
{
    var n;
    var score = 0;
    var number = randomnumber();
    for (n = 0 ; n < 11 ; ++n)
    {
        if (number == 0){
            score += 0;
        }
        else if (number == 2)
        {
            score += 2;
        }
        else if (number == 3)
        {
            score += 3;
        }
        document.write(score)
    }
}

</SCRIPT>
<HEAD>
<BODY>
<BODY BGCOLOUR = "WHITE">
<H2>The Foundation Page </H2>
<HR>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE = "Javascript"> main() </SCRIPT>
<INPUT NAME = "dobutton" TYPE = "button" value = "Start game" on Click = "game()"> 
<INPUT NAME = "dobutton" TYPE = "button" value = "Leaderboard" on Click = "leader()">
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

EDIT: If I understand your comment correctly, you should be doing something like this

```
function totalscore() 
{
    var n;
    var score = 0;
    for (n = 0 ; n < 10 ; ++n)
    {
        score += randomnumber();
        document.write(score)
    }
    var grandTotal = score;
}
```

Comment: And do you know how do i sum them all together to get a grand total?

Comment: I am not sure what do you want to sum up bro. Please explain a little

Comment: Sorry about the lack of explanation, What im trying to do is to sum up all of the 10 value that was produced by the random number generator and incremental counter.

Comment: I have made an edit, hope I understand you correctly

Comment: Sorry, i still dont quite get it. What im trying to do is to add all of the 10 value from the random number generator. The incremental counter is suppose to produce 10 random value instead of 1 and sum them all together. I hope it clarify the situation.

Comment: Can you clarify what does "score +=" mean please?

Comment: It requests a random number 10 times and in each iteration, it adds current value to the previous score and prints that to the document. After the for loop, you will have a grand total sum, you can do something with it.

Comment: So should "score=score + 0" or "score = score + 1" be the same thing as what you wrote?

Comment: score += X is the same as score = score + X :)

Comment: Ok, i did what you ask now sadly, it will only produce a value of 1,2 and 3 throughout the 10 number. E.G. (0,0,0,0,0.....) , (1,1,1,1,1....) (2,2,2,2,2....) what method do you suggest i do?

Comment: You did something wrong, I just tried and it works. See the image, use that url and the same code and just keep clicking the button and you will see different result http://shrani.si/f/2b/dz/1OYqQIe1/javascript.png

Answer (score 1):

Variable `score` is declared in your `totalscore` function but never initialised. Adding anything to `undefined` gives `NaN`, which is what your function writes to the page.